# Floatting points issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, floating-point

I have taken two UITextFields & one label to get the result of the float value inserted in the textfields. This is the code which I have done.
Here issue starts when I initially takes textfields value in float, it is getting changed.

```
- (IBAction)btnCalculateAmountSelected:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"[_txtField1.text floatValue] is:--> %f ----- [_txtField2.text floatValue] is:--> %f",[_txtField1.text floatValue],[_txtField2.text floatValue]);

    float result = [_txtField1.text floatValue] - [_txtField2.text floatValue];
    NSLog(@"actual result is:--> %f",result);

    float truncatedFloat = truncf(result * 100) / 100.0;
    NSLog(@"truncatedFloat is:--> %f",truncatedFloat);

    _lblResult.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", truncatedFloat];
    NSLog(@"_lblResult.text is:--> %@",_lblResult.text);
}
```

[image]

**output is:-**

```
[_txtField1.text floatValue] is:--> 1234.123413 ----- [_txtField2.text floatValue] is:--> 1234.111084
actual result is:--> 0.012329
truncatedFloat is:--> 0.010000
_lblResult.text is:--> 0.010000
```

Comment: ?? what is your question ??

Comment: What you wanna exactly ?

Comment: Here issue starts when I initially takes textfields value in float, it is getting changed.

Comment: you can get idea by the output i have printed using NSLog.

Comment: what you are expecting as output?

Comment: @Sunny I wanted to calculate exact value which is entered into both the textfields.

Comment: Can anybody, from the list who have closed this question, let me know why it is not a real question ? If you do not have an answer for this question please take your precious suggestion back. And it is fine if you can not answer or up vote the question. But at least you should not do negative marketing. Especially :- https://stackoverflow.com/users/41116/abizern, https://stackoverflow.com/users/151019/mark, https://stackoverflow.com/users/298225/eric-postpischil, https://stackoverflow.com/users/656600/rptwsthi, https://stackoverflow.com/users/6615/pilsetnieks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So two responses:

1) floats have limited precision - if you want more precision use doubles not floats.

2) If your issue is that you are dealing with currency, say dollars and cents, keep your values as cents, and when displayed cents are the amount modulo 100 and the dollars are cents/100 - you will never get odd values if you do this.

Comment: Or use `NSDecimalNumber`

Comment: @david-h Thanks...This is working properly & giving the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Use double as a data types

like
double result = [_txtField1.text doubleValue] - [_txtField2.text doubleValue];

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use this one.You know Every float variable return 6 values after Dot . So please use **%.4f** instead of **%f** .

```
NSLog(@"[_txtField1.text floatValue] is:--> %.4f ----- [_txtField2.text floatValue] is:--> %.4f",[_txtField1.text floatValue],[_txtField2.text floatValue]);
```

Output :

**[_txtField1.text floatValue] is:--> 1234.1234 ----- [_txtField2.text floatValue] is:--> 1234.1111**

I hope you got your answer.

Comment: in this case if any values after 4th decimal will be then it will be considered at the time of calculation.

Comment: Yes you are right.Because i thought you wanna only print this value So i've given this answer.

Comment: That's perfectly right...but you can see the values which I have entered into textFields and NSLog for the textfields values are totally different.

Comment: thats y i was give answer for only 4 values after dot